# c++ object bind itself's lifetime to lambdas

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a window and a controller object. They are not tight coupled, but the controller bind itself to window events (via boost::signals2) and I want the controller to be destroyed, if the window is destroyed (or if all of its event handlers are replaced/removed). The idea was, to bind lambdas to `shared_from_this`.

`... boost::bind(&MyController::OnInitialize, shared_from_this())`.

This could (actually) all be done in the constructor of my controller, but I get the bad_weak_ptr exception, because before the first `shared_from_this` call, the object must be managed by a `shared_ptr` (the docs say).

In other words: `shared_from_this` in the ctor is never possible.

current Solution: My work-around is an empty ctor and a `BindSignals` method which is called after object was create via `make_shared`.

Questions:

- I actually don't need the controller after I created it, thus `make_shared` and `BindSignals` is boilerplate code, but is it a good idea?
- Is it allowed to create a temporary `shared_ptr(this)` to be able to call `shared_from_this()` after?
- For another developer using my controller, it's hard to see, that it must be created on the heap and managed by a `shared_ptr`. Maybe indicates, that controller ctor should be private and instantiated via static method, doing it correctly?
- Are there better ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you!